# java select statement is not working

Tags: java, jdbc, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to return records from a table in an Access DB(2010), but every time I run the statement I keep getting this error:

Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`
where I initialized **stmt**

I didnt display the name of the database in this code. Here is my code:

```
public class util {

static String path = "path to db";         
static String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+path;

  static Connection conn ; 
  static Statement s;

 public static boolean  ajouterFormule(String formule){
     boolean success = false;
      PreparedStatement stmt;
    try{
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", ""); 
       String ajout_sql = "INSERT INTO FORMULE(form_nom)"
             + "VALUES(?)";

       stmt= conn.prepareStatement(ajout_sql);
       stmt.setString(1, formule);
       int num_row = stmt.executeUpdate();
       if(num_row > 0)
           success =true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             System.out.println("ERROR2");
    }
     return success;
 }


public static String[] getFormule()throws SQLException{
  String[] arr = new String[10];
   String getFormSql = "SELECT form_nom, form_statut "
            + "from formule";
    int i=0;
      System.out.println("NO");
    //Statement stmt = null;
    // ResultSet rs ;
    try{                   
        Statement stmt =  conn.createStatement();
      //  System.out.println(stmt);
        stmt.execute(getFormSql);
        ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
           String txt = rs.getString("form_nom");
    //       arr[i] = rs.getString("form_nom");
           System.out.println("Nothing..."+txt);

           i++;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          System.out.println("Error..");
    }
    System.out.print("Length "+ arr.length);

    return arr;
}
```

}

Comment: It seems 'conn' is null, so the statement cannot be created

Answer (score 2):

getFromSql is equal to "SELECT form_nom,form_statutfrom formule", you have to write :

```
String getFormSql = "SELECT form_nom,form_statut "
            + "from formule";
```

note the space ' ' after statut

Edit:
Also when you do that

```
Statement stmt =  conn.createStatement();
      //  System.out.println(stmt);
        stmt.execute(getFormSql);
        ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
```

You read your ResultSet from a different statement than the one you just executed.

Edit bis: 
The way you initialize your connection is screwed up too. It is a static field, but you only initialize it if you call your insert method 'ajouterFormule' :

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```

you don't do it in your select method 'getFormule', so if you select without inserting first your connection will be null.

Remove your static fields (conn and s) and use local fields in each method for your connection and your statement (and also, you should close them once you're done inserting/selecting).

Comment: Yea its true, I added the space,but it didn't solved the main problem

Comment: See my edit with the confusion between s and stmt. Get rid of "static Statement s;" this is awful.

Comment: True! I fixed that too,but the error message is still the same

Comment: Ok but isnt better if I declared them only once?? Thats what i've been trying to do but it didnt work,even when i was initializing the connection in the constructor

Comment: No, it's not better. You need a connection and a statement per query, and sharing them between your select and your insert is dangerous and not thread-safe at all. The thing you can "share" is "Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");", you can put it in a static block.

Comment: What is true is that calling getConnection for each query is not very efficient, you might want to consider using a connection pool depending on the needs of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't initialize `conn` anywhere.

You need to initialize it before accessing it.

Comment: I edited my code so now u can see the connection. I can even add too the DB ,but i cant get record with the select statement..